# Oracle Where 'TEXT' matches something by a certain percentage

Tags: sql, oracle, function, pattern-matching, match

I remember seeing someone use a function in Oracle where they could specify a percentage of text matching. For example:

`0123456789` would match this: `1123456789` by 90% or something (I'm no mathematician, but hopefully you get the idea...)

I can't quite think of the right keywords to search for to find the function I'm looking for. Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks.

It would probably look something like this:

```
select *
from something s
where matches(s.textcolumn, 'Matching Text') > .9
```

Comment: Are you thinking of [`utl_match`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10577/u_match.htm)?

Comment: have you tried at tomkyte.oracle.com

Comment: @RayToal, that's the one! Thanks. If you answer the question I'll accept it so anyone else with a similar question will find it easily :) Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package you are looking for is [`utl_match`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10577/u_match.htm).

It contains functions for comaparing strings by edit distance and similarity.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks. You don't think you could help me with a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703609/utl-match-with-clob) do you?