# UTL_MATCH-like function to work with CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle, pattern-matching, string-matching, clob

**My question is:** Is there a [`UTL_MATCH`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10577/u_match.htm#CHDGDIDJ)-like function which works with a `CLOB` rather than a `VARCHAR2`?

**My specific problem is:** I'm on an Oracle database. I have a bunch of pre-written queries which interface with Domo [CenterView](http://www.domo.com/solutions/centerview). The queries have variables in them defined by `${variableName}`. I need to rewrite these queries. I didn't write the original so instead of figuring out what a good value for the variables should be I want to run the queries with the application and get what the query was from [`V$SQL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2113.htm).

**So my solution is:** Do a `UTL_MATCH` on the queries with the variable stuff in it and `V$SQL.SQL_FULLTEXT`. However, `UTL_MATCH` is limited to `VARCHAR2` and the datatype of `V$SQL.SQL_FULLTEXT` is `CLOB`. So, this is why I'm looking for a `UTL_MATCH`-like function which works with a `CLOB` datatype.

*Any other tips of how to accomplish this are welcome. Thanks!*

**Edit, about the tips.** If you have a better idea of how to do this, let me just tell you some information I've got at my disposal. I have about 100 queries, they're all in an excel spreadsheet (the ones with the `${variableName}` in them). So I could pretty easily use excel to write a query for me. I'm hoping to just union all those queries together and copy the output to another sheet. Anyway, maybe that's helpful if you're thinking there's a better way to do this.

**An example:** Let's say I have the following query from Domo:

```
select department.dept_name
from department
where department.id = '${selectedDepartmentId}'
;
```

I want to call something like this:

```
select v.sql_fulltext
from v$sql v
where utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(v.sql_fulltext,
'select department.dept_name
from department
where department.id = ''${selectedDepartmentId}''') > 90
;
```

And get something like this in return:

```
SQL_FULLTEXT
------------------------------------------
select department.dept_name
from department
where department.id = '154'
```

**What I've tried:**

I tried substringing the clob and casting it to a varchar. I was really hopeful this would work, but it gives me an error. Here's the code:

```
select v.sql_fulltext
from v$sql v
where  utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity( cast( substr (v.sql_fulltext, 0, 4000) as varchar2 (4000)),
'select department.dept_name
from department
where department.id = ''${selectedDepartmentId}''') > 90
;
```

And here's the error:

`ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 8000, maximum: 4000)`

However, if I run this it works fine:

```
select cast(substr(v.sql_fulltext, 0, 4000) as varchar2 (4000))
from v$sql v
;
```

So I'm not sure what the problem is with casting the substring...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom function for it. Here's the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function match_clob(clob_1 clob, clob_2 clob) return number as

similar number := 0;
sec_similar number := 0;
sections number := 0;
max_length number := 3949;
length_1 number;
length_2 number;
vchar_1 varchar2 (3950);
vchar_2 varchar2 (3950);

begin
  length_1 := length(clob_1);
  length_2 := length(clob_2);
  --dbms_output.put_line('length_1: '||length_1);
  --dbms_output.put_line('length_2: '||length_2);
  IF length_1 > max_length or length_2 > max_length THEN

    FOR x IN 1 .. ceil(length_1 / max_length) LOOP

      --dbms_output.put_line('((x-1)*max_length) + 1'||(x-1)||' * '||max_length||' = '||(((x-1)*max_length) + 1));

      vchar_1 := substr(clob_1, ((x-1)*max_length) + 1, max_length);
      vchar_2 := substr(clob_2, ((x-1)*max_length) + 1, max_length);

--      dbms_output.put_line('Section '||sections||' vchar_1: '||vchar_1||' ==> vchar_2: '||vchar_2);

      sec_similar := UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY(vchar_1, vchar_2);

      --dbms_output.put_line('sec_similar: '||sec_similar);

      similar := similar + sec_similar;
      sections := sections + 1;

    END LOOP;

    --dbms_output.put_line('Similar: '||similar||' ==> Sections: '||sections);
    similar := similar / sections;

  ELSE
    similar := UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY(clob_1,clob_2);
  END IF;
  --dbms_output.put_line('Overall Similar: '||similar);
   return(similar);
end;
/
```

Comment: You should be able to set max_length, vchar_1, and vchar_2 to 32767.  The maximum character limit is different for SQL and PL/SQL.

Comment: Good point, I'll give it a shot and update the method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

UTL_MATCH is a packaging for comparing strings with regards for checking how similar two strings are.  Its functions evaluate strings and return scores.  So all you're going to get is a number indicating (say) how many edits you need to turn `${variableName}` into "Farmville" or "StackOveflow".

What you won't get is the actual differences: these two strings of text are identical except at offset 123 where it replaces `${variableName}` with "Farmville".

Putting it like that suggests an alternative approach.  Using [INSTR()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i998546) and [SUBSTR()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i999349) to locate instances of `${variableName}` in your Domo CenterView queries and use those offsets to identify the different text in the `v$sql.fulltext` equivalents.  You can do this with CLOB in PL/SQL with the [DBMS_LOB package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm).

Comment: I may have not been clear enough in my original question. However your answer may work as an alternative way to do it. What I meant though is I just want to find the queries which have been run on the server which are similar to the domo queries. I'm not trying to replace the variables with what actually existed necessarily, I'm just trying to find that query as it was actually run and just use that. I don't know whether I've made any sense just now, but I'll look into that link you provided. Thanks.

Comment: Far from being "not clear enough" your original question, with its reference to UTL_MATCH, is positively misleading.

Comment: Really? I thought it was pretty clear. I don't care to find where the variables are and replace them or anything. I'm only interested in finding the query which is similar enough to the one with the variables that I have a working query to rewrite. How do you suggest I improve the question?

Answer (score 1):

If the text you want to search has length <= 32767, then you can just convert the `CLOB` to `VARCHAR2` using `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR`:

```
select v.sql_fulltext 
from v$sql v 
where utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(dbms_lob.substr(v.sql_fulltext), 'select department.dept_name from department where department.id = ''${selectedDepartmentId}''') > 90 ;
```

Comment: Just tried it and it gave me the following error: `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small`

Comment: This can work, but you'll need to use it in a PL/SQL context to allow a VARCHAR2 to use 32767 characters.  You'll need to fetch the values into a CLOB, convert or substr them into a VARCHAR2, and then loop through the results and call the UTL_MATCH package.